# Regular-Expression capture word in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I try to replace some HTML-Tags in a code snippet. E.g. a span-element is to replace when it has no id, but it isn't to replace when it has an id.

Here is my approach:

```
var sHTML = 'Text abc <span> text def ';
sHTML = sHTML.replace(/<\s*\/*\s*span(.[^(id\=)]*){0,1}?>/ig, '');
alert(sHTML);
```

It works wrong! Because it must not replace when "id=" occurs, but in case of occur of some single character like "i" or "d" or "=" it shouldn't make any difference, and it has to replace.
In other words, I expect for:
`var sHTML = 'Text abc <span id=MyId > text def ';` Nothing is to replace, because the span-element has an id, so it should be remain as it is as follows: `Text abc <span id=MyId >  text def`.

But for `var sHTML = 'Text abc <span style="color:#00ff00;" > text def ';`
it has to replace, because the span-element has no id as follows: `Text abc  text def`.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span (?![^>]*id)[^>]*>[ ]*|<\/span>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/82

```
var re = /<span (?![^>]*id)[^>]*>[ ]*|<\/span>/gim;
var str = 'Text abc <span style="color:#00ff00;" > text def \'; \nText abc <span id=MyId > text def \nText <span color="red" >abc</span>';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```